# What can cause a 'casual' MySQL DELETE/UPDATE query to get stuck until manual kill?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unix, webserver

I've started to suffer from a weird in-ability of my MySQL server to not complete 'casual' update/delete queries. My definition of 'casual' is queries that are plain-vanilla, and happen all the time, and all of a sudden one of these just gets stuck and never finishes. The server disks I/O is high during this time (from ~65% normally to over 90%, this increase is in READS) and only when I manually kill the query everything returns to normal. This happens every couple of hours, each time on a different table. It seems the stuck query will never finish (saw more than 6hrs). When looking at the running queries during such an event, the is no 'waiting for table lock'.

What can cause this?
I'm thinking of adding a cronjob that will automatically kill long running queries, but that will be a bandage that I would rather avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem ended up being related to a table with a primary key which is INT, and a query that is trying to delete a key which is over the data-type range, and referencing it with parenthesis. I don't know why, but this hangs in my configuration:

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE pk="TOO_BIGINT"
```

These however, don't:

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE pk=TOO_BIGINT
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE pk="TOO_BIGINT"
```

If you ever needed another reason to use PDO...

Answer (score 0):

Some times the tables on which mysql query is running get locked, due to some previous un-finished query and due to corrupted state.
My suggestion would be to check for locks on the respective tables

Comment: During such an event I'm not seeing any 'waiting for table level lock'. Is there any known corrupted engine state that can effect many tables at once?

Comment: Not sure whether this will work or not, but it can be given a shot - "Try acquiring exclusive lock for the respective operation on the table in question and then execute that query on that table and then unlock it once query execution is finished". If this doesnt work, I would look into the memory usage of my system when that query is running. 3rd thing you can also try looking to mysql "explain" command for that sql query which you are using